# Consider the action of $S_3$ on itself by conjugation. Describe the orbits of (1, 2) and (1, 2, 3) under this action.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, symmetric-groups

Find the stabilizer subgroup of each of these elements. How many orbits are there in total?

For the cycles (1 2) and (1 2 3). I am getting the orbit of these cycles as follows: 
Orb(1 2) = {(1 3),(1 2),(2 3)} 
Orb(1 2 3) = { (1 3 2),(1), (1 2 3)} 
The stabilizer group is as follows: 
Stab(1 2) = {(1),(1 2)} 
Stab(1 2 3) = {(1), (1 2 3)}

I have calculated the Orbit and Stabilizer subgroups of these elements by putting elements of $ S_3$. Is there any easier way to compute them. Are my answers correct?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: How did you conclude that $(1,2,3)$ and $(1)$ were conjugate? Also note that stabilizers are subgroups, but $\{(1), (1,2,3)\}$ is not a subgroup.